# How to prevent double booking of a room in this hotel booking database design?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have two tables for hotel booking. One is rooms table where I save room type, hotelId and total number of rooms that the hotel has for that type.

| HotelId | RoomTypeId | RoomType | TotalRooms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2 | Premium | 24 |
| 100 | 3 | SeaView | 10 |

I have Bookings table where I keep record of all the reservations.

| BookinId | RoomTypeId | HotelId | RoomsBooked | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2 | 100 | 3 | 2023-03-17 14:00 | 2023-03-20 11:00 |
| 1002 | 2 | 100 | 2 | 2023-03-17 14:00 | 2023-03-20 11:00 |
| 1003 | 3 | 100 | 1 | 2023-03-17 14:00 | 2023-03-20 11:00 |

When a user tries to book a room of a specific type(say premium) in a hotel. I do below two things:

1. Using sql query, get the sum of number of all the premium rooms booked in the hotel from Bookings table and subtract it from the TotalRooms of the premium room for that hotel from Rooms table. This gives me the number of available rooms.
2. If available rooms > 0, I insert a new booking record in the Bookings table.

How can I prevent double booking in this scenario? For example, when there is only one premium room left and two users try to book it for the same DateTime, step 1 may get that available rooms is 1 for both users and then step 2 may insert duplicate record in Bookings table.

Comment: Why don't you store bookings for each separate hotel room? (How else will you make sure a guest doesn't have to move from one room to another when staying several nights.)

Comment: when a record is inserted in the bookings table, it means that the room is available for the entire stay of the guest.

Comment: Which room is booked?

Comment: Room can be assigned later by the hotel staff. As long as we know that there is at least one room available, we want to take the booking.

Comment: Also I was thinking of doing step 1 and step 2 in a transaction with isolation level set to serialization. Imo, that should fail one transaction. is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

The current design will definitely cause double booking. To avoid double booking using the current scheme, you need to lock both tables when a new request comes and relinquish the locks when the request is addressed.

You would require to calculate the number of available rooms by the same process but user request processing needs to be serialized. A user request can be executed only if all the previous requests are addressed.

This process however is very expensive and leads to a bad user experience. One way to expedite the process could be by keeping a table of available rooms (total - used) per room type.

You could use optimistic concurrency control on the available rooms. This is the schema

**Available Rooms Table**

room Type |   available |  version

2|             11 |         1

Now if a request comes for room Type 2, you check the available column of the room type in the Available rooms table and update that by subtracting 1 from the available column after the booking and bumping the version.

You can only bump the version if the version is the same as the one you read at the beginning of the request processing.

Read --> (2, 11, 1) (roomType, available, version)
Write --> (2, 10, 2) (roomType, available = available -1, version = version+1)

The table has the same version for the roomType column,i.e version =1 hence the write is successful.

Now, if some other request has changed the version from 1->2 before you get a chance to do that, you fail the request and retry.

**Available Rooms Table**

room Type |   available|   version

2 |           10   |       2

Read --> (2, 11, 1) (roomType, available, version)
Write --> (2, 10, 2) (roomType, available = available -1, version = version+1)
The table has a different version for the roomType column,i.e version =2 hence the write failed and the request needs to be retried.

**Good resources**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-an-optimistic-concurrency-control-in-dbms
- https://cult.honeypot.io/reads/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-concurrency/

Comment: But won't I have to create a record in available rooms for every possible future date? user can check for any date and then i will have to maintain a record for each roomtype for each hotel for that date.

Comment: Yes, that's the tricky part. I would suggest you see the solution here: https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/designing-a-data-model-for-a-hotel-room-booking-system/ 

Essentially, instead of having the available rooms per date, it maintains the occupied ones.

Comment: I am also maintaining the occupied ones in Bookings table.